# ASP Master and Content Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages, content-pages

I am using Master and Content Pages, now I have a situation that I dont want to use the css of Master page on Content Page.
There are alots of classes and css files so overriding them is not possible I just have option to not include them in content page.

So what are the possible scenarios?

Comment: Create a new master page which does not include the CSS in question and have that particular content page use that master page.

Comment: If this is the solution then i have an idea to create 1 Master then 2 Child Masters, so that all common will be in Master then content based css in respective Child Masters.

Comment: I believe that's the best way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

Having in mind that every equivalent method between the MasterPage and the ContentPage is being executed always later by the MasterPage (see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dct97kc3.aspx)), *we have to introduce the CSS change inside the MasterPage*.

That being said, you can detect the name of the ContentPage actually being displayed inside the Masterpage using *Page.AppRelativeVirtualPath.ToString()* in your *ContentPlaceHolder*.

Then, you can modify the css inside the masterpage saving it in an asp:Literal that includes the HTML link tag.

For example:

**MasterPage.aspx**

```html
<head>
   <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="cssStyleSheet">
</head>
<body>
   <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="contentPageHolder" runat="server">
</body>
```

**MasterPage.aspx.cs**

```
public void ModifyCSS(){
string contentPageName = contentPageHolder.Page.AppRelativeVirtualPath.ToString();
int pos = contentPageName.LastIndexOf("/") + 1;
contentPageName = contentPageName.SubString(pos, contentPageName.Length -pos);

switch(contentPageName)
{
  case "Login.aspx": 
  cssStyleSheet.Text = @"<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='Styles/Login.css' />";

    break;

  case "Logout.aspx": 
  cssStyleSheet.Text = @"<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='Styles/Logout.css' />"; 
    break;       
}}
```